# Zend2 - how to get access to model not in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

my zend2 application have some functions moved to other sources, for example my controller looks like this:

```
public function someAction() {
  $logic = new \Home\Logic\Home($this->getServiceLocator);

  return ('data' => $logic->getSomeStuff());
}
```

I like this way of building my application, cuz I was used to do it this way in Zend1, which makes my code pretty simple and easy to read/edit. Whole logic wasn't part of controller code. In Zend2 I have many problems with that - first thing - I have to push serviceLocator in my logic constructor - which is very bad solution for me. :( Sometimes I need to have access to model in view - for many reasons (for example to get easy access to dictionary fields - that means in table owners I have id_car, which links to table cars. I don't want to make view for that but just point in my model owners which field should be used in view to read from another model... Let's take a look at my Logic now:

```
public function getSomeStuff() {
  $model = $this->serviceLocator->get('someTable');

  return $model->fetchAll();
}
```

My question is - how to get access to my models without pushing serviceLocator from controller to my logic?

EDIT: example for my view (the passed data is $data) index.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->partial('/partial/show_some_table.phtml', array('data' => $data)); ?>
```

And the partial (thats how I see it):

```
$this->placeHolder('table-body')->captureStart();
foreach ($this->data as $data) {
  if (isset($data['dictionary']) {
    $dic = new \Home\Logic\Dictionary($data['dictionary']); // this thing should return my dictionary which translate given id to text representation
    echo $dic[$data['field']];
  } else {
    echo $data['field'];
  }
}
$this->placeHolder('table-body')->captureEnd();
```

Something similar to this.

And the $data['dictionary'] would keep: name of table which should be used to get field text representation, name of id field of dictionary, name of text field of dictionary. So if I pass: array('Cars', 'id', 'name') then my dictionary should know that I want to open table Cars and get as return array of id=>name.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear how your app works from these examples, but to answer your question, if `Home\Logic\Home` needs access to the `someTable` service, you pass that in as a dependency. Rather than passing the whole service locator in via. the constructor, you tell ZF2 how to create the `Home\Logic\Home` instance, using a factory.

In your Module.php:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Home\Logic\Home' => function($sm) {
                $someTable = $sm->get('someTable');
                $home = new \Home\Logic\Home($someTable);

                return $home;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Modify the home class to accept that object in its constructor:

```
namespace Home\Logic;

class Home
{
    protected $someTable;

    public function __construct($someTable)
    {
        $this->someTable = $someTable;
    }
}
```

then in your controller, get the service manager to create the `Home\Logic\Home` instance for you instead:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $logic = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Home\Logic\Home');

    return ('data' => $logic->getSomeStuff());
}
```

now `Home\Logic\Home` automatically has access to the `someTable` class.

Comment: Thanks, could you also tell me how to access to my models directly from view? I mean for example in file /partial/some_table_view.phtml

Comment: You can only access models you pass to the view model. How are you rendering your views? Your example code seems a bit non-standard and doesn't have anything view related.

Comment: I've edited my post. I hope u understand my conception.

Comment: I'm still not too clear on how you're wanting this to work, but it does sound like some of this logic should be in a view helper instead.